# Add VMware graphics driver to a PXE bootable Thin Client initrd.img file

Tags: graphics, vmware, pxe

How to add VMware graphics driver to a pxe bootable thin client initrd.img file?

I have the VMs for the Ubuntu 12 Server and the pxe bootable Thin Client in the VMware Workstation 11. The Thin Client works fine in one monitor mode (unity). I need to enable dual monitor mode for this Thin Client VM.

In order to enable this dual monitor mode in the VMware Workstation, the VMware graphics driver or VMware-Tools is required to be installed in this pxe bootable Thin Client.

So, how can I do it? One option that I think is to add the VMware graphics display driver in the Thin Client initrd.img. Are there other options?